# Is there OLE provider drivers for a production web server that can be installed without installing the full office app?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, webforms

I have a web application that creates a connection to an OLE DB provider.  It allows you to upload .xls/.xlsx files to the server which get the data gets stripped out to datatable which eventually is passed to a stored procedure.

I was told about free ACE 2010 drivers. The only link I could find was the following, but if this is the free ACE drivers, it states on there about not using this for a production web server as if its strictly for development.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=7554f536-8c28-4598-9b72-ef94e038c891&displaylang=en

Is there drivers I can install on the server that wouldn't require me installing the Excel application?

Comment: The link you provided does not exclude usage on a production server, it just states that the intent of the drivers is for usage in developing applications. All their disclaimer really means is "Don't come crying to us if it doesn't work for you."

Comment: @Joel - ok thanks for the clarification.  So have I stumbled across the correct drivers for doing what I stated?

Comment: Yes, I would say so. I've used these drivers in a couple of production configurations to access legacy resources that were upgraded to newer versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your link is broken: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=c06b8369-60dd-4b64-a44b-84b371ede16d&displaylang=en

> Supported Operating Systems:Windows
>   7;Windows Server 2003 R2 (32-Bit
>   x86);Windows Server 2003 R2 x64
>   editions;Windows Server 2008
>   R2;Windows Server 2008 Service Pack
>   2;Windows Vista Service Pack 1;Windows
>   XP Service Pack 3

Note that Jet is installed by default with any even vaguely recent version of Windows.